# open url with urllib2 that already have get parameter

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to get data from pages like http://www.site.com/list?a=data&b=data...
I retrieve all those url from a page of site.com. When trying to open a link, I get error: TypeError: expected BaseHandler instance, got .

My guess is that url need to be "encoded" but how ?

Thanks for your help guys!

---

Edit: 
Ok, here is the code, So all connection pass by my proxy server and try to open the url found earlier like described above.

Code:

```
tileurl = 'http://www.site.com/list?a=data&b=data'
proxy = SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, '192.168.0.190', 12500)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
infile = opener.open(tileurl)
tile_bin = infile.read()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\Jean-michel\Dropbox\Projects\Python Code\Maps Saver\map.py", line 89, in <module> opener = urllib2.build_opener(tileurl) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 490, in build_opener opener.add_handler(h) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 326, in add_handler type(handler)) 
TypeError: expected BaseHandler instance, got type 'str'
```

Comment: Show your code first.

Comment: Do you have the option of installing [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and just using that instead? It's infinitely easier to use correctly than are the standard library equivalents.

Comment: Are there quote marks around the URL? And can you copy-and-paste the actual traceback so that we can see the unedited error message?

Comment: Well all the program is using urllib2 and this is the last part of it that parse web... after that it's just mysql manipulation...

Comment: You need to make your question clearer to understand so it can be answered. If you do what Kirk asks, we probably can help you.

Comment: Be sure to edit your question as opposed to putting the output in the comments...

Comment: url is retrieved from a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tileurl = tile.replace(t1, "") ## Removing the parameters from the url
p = urlparse.parse_qs(t1) ## decoding the parameter
tileparam = urllib.urlencode(p) ## encoding the parameter...
```

Problem solved!! :)